# No container found for postgres_1 in CircleCI

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, circleci, postgresql-9.6

I have circleCI script where it runs `docker-compose exec postgres pg_isready` command setup in Azure containers but we are getting a code build error as shown below. The same script was running fine earlier but from past few days we are getting this.

```
running docker-compose up
Creating network "docker_default" with the default driver
Pulling postgres (postgres:9.6)...
9.6: Pulling from library/postgres


Status: Downloaded newer image for postgres:9.6

Creating docker_myproject_1 ... 

Creating docker_postgres_1 ... 

waiting for postgres to startAttaching to docker_myproject_1
ERROR: No container found for postgres_1
myproject_1  | 2020-02-18T14:40:42.317723661Z starting...
.myproject_1  | 2020-02-18T14:40:43.718394751Z {"name":"myproject","hostname":"xxxxxx","pid":1,"level":30,"msg":"myproject app version v2.8 listening on port 3030 (Node.js version 8.17.0, ci environment)","time":"2020-02-18T14:40:43.717Z","v":0}
myproject_1  | 2020-02-18T14:40:43.718573206Z myproject app version v2.8 listening on port 3030 (Node.js version 8.17.0, ci environment)
myproject_1  | 2020-02-18T14:40:43.793220191Z Failed to prune sessions: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND postgres postgres:5432
ERROR: No container found for postgres_1
.ERROR: No container found for postgres_1
.ERROR: No container found for postgres_1
.ERROR: No container found for postgres_1
.ERROR: No container found for postgres_1
.ERROR: No container found for postgres_1
.ERROR: No container found for postgres_1
.ERROR: No container found for postgres_1
.ERROR: No container found for postgres_1
.ERROR: No container found for postgres_1
.ERROR: No container found for postgres_1
.ERROR: No container found for postgres_1
.ERROR: No container found for postgres_1
.ERROR: No container found for postgres_1
.ERROR: No container found for postgres_1
.Too many attempts
```

CircleCI config file --- config.yml

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: /home/circleci/app

    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:8-browsers
      - image: circleci/postgres:9.6-alpine
        environment:
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_DB: myproject_ci

    steps:
      # Prepare build environment
      - setup_remote_docker:
          reusable: true
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          key: dependency-cache-v2-{{ checksum "package.json" }}

      # Install dependencies + cache them
      - run: npm install
      - save_cache:
          key: dependency-cache-v2-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
          paths:
            - node_modules

      # Build
      - run: CONFIG_ENV=ci npm run build

      # Start for testing
      - run:
          command: ./scripts/run-ci.sh
          background: true
      - run: ./scripts/run-ci-wait.sh

      # Run tests
      - run: CONFIG_ENV=ci npm test

      # Run tests for docker image
      - run: ./test/docker/run-docker-tests.sh

      - deploy:
          name: Deploy master to dev
          command: |
            if [ "${CIRCLE_BRANCH}" == "master" ]; then
              ./scripts/deploy-dev.sh
            fi
```

Contents of run-docker-tests.sh where it is failing

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
cd $DIR

function cleanup() {
  docker-compose down || true
}
trap cleanup SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT

echo 'running docker-compose down'
docker-compose down
echo 'running docker-compose up'
docker-compose up -d --force-recreate
docker-compose logs --follow --timestamps --no-color myproject &

printf 'waiting for postgres to start'
attempt=0
until docker-compose exec postgres pg_isready; do
  printf '.'
  sleep 2
  attempt=$(( $attempt + 1 ))
  if [ $attempt -gt 15 ]; then
    echo Too many attempts
    exit 1
  fi
done
echo 'postgres is started'

printf 'waiting for server to start'
attempt=0
until docker-compose run -T myproject curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail http://myproject:3030; do
  printf '.'
  sleep 2
  attempt=$(( $attempt + 1 ))
  if [ $attempt -gt 15 ]; then
    echo Too many attempts
    exit 1
  fi
done
echo 'server is started'
```

Success build with the same script in the past week.

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for postgres:9.6

Creating docker_postgres_1 ... 

Creating docker_myproject_1 ... 

waiting for postgres to startAttaching to docker_myproject_1
myproject_1  | 2020-02-14T14:57:56.436816113Z starting...
^@^@/var/run/postgresql:5432 - no response
myproject_1  | 2020-02-14T14:57:58.305638546Z {"name":"myproject","hostname":"xxxxxx","pid":1,"level":30,"msg":"myproject app version v2 listening on port 3030 (Node.js version 8.17.0, ci environment)","time":"2020-02-14T14:57:58.305Z","v":0}
myproject_1  | 2020-02-14T14:57:58.306243774Z myproject app version v2 listening on port 3030 (Node.js version 8.17.0, ci environment)
.myproject_1  | 2020-02-14T14:57:58.413266214Z Failed to prune sessions: connect ECONNREFUSED x.x.x.x:5432
/var/run/postgresql:5432 - no response
./var/run/postgresql:5432 - accepting connections
postgres is started
waiting for server to startserver is started
```

Compose file

```
version: "3"

services:
  myproject:
    image: myproject:latest
    environment:
      - CONFIG_ENV=ci
      - CONFIG_PASSWORD
      - POSTGRES_HOST=postgres
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=myproject_ci
```

Any help here would be great.

Comment: Would be useful to include your docker-compose file, or at least the relevant parts

Comment: Where do you run the docker-compose command? And do you share your docker-compose file?

Comment: Updated the description with docker compose file (config.yml and run-docker-tests.sh file where the error is occurring). Am I missing anything here? Because the same script was running perfectly fine and from past few days I am facing this issue.

Comment: I too am facing this issue.


@QuintenScheppermans, now that the docker-compose file contents have been shared, can you please suggest the solution.

Comment: @CharlesXu , any solution?

Comment: Sorry, is that really docker-compose file? Which platform do you use?

Comment: You're only allowing 15 attempts, perhaps it's taking longer for some reason? Is the postgress container healthy at some point? Do you have any logs from your postgres instance?

Comment: Yes, that is the compose file where we use CirceCI. @QuintenScheppermans postgres container is still showing healthy in Azure.

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `docker-compose.yml` file, please check if provided under `environment` parameter. 
If it is not provided, please provide something like this: `- POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust`.

This solution had worked for us and the cause for this build issue should have been that Docker Official Images for `Postgres` had been updated recently which has lead to a host of new issues with previously working PG containers throwing errors on initialization now.

More information here:
https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/commit/044fa382fb4ce789c44636bf5ca1b4aca253fa0f#diff-24ff720298244763c283810044b398c8